# how to get my Current custom User in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, zk

I am using spring security for authentication. I created a custom user who extends from `User` ,then I used it in my customServiceDetails (implementation of `UserDetailsService` ) , I want to be able to get my custom user, so I tried to do this :

```
public class MyUser extends User implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String uuid;

    public MyUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
            boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);

    }

    public MyUser(String username, String password, String uuid,
            boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}
```

I tried to get the current user by doing this but it's not working :

```
 (MyUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

I wonder if there is any suggestion ?

Comment: When you say it didn't work...did you get an error (like maybe a ClassCastException), or did you just get a null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Zk framework so the solution was like that :

```
MyUser user =(MyUser)((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) Executions.getCurrent().getUserPrincipal()).getPrincipal();
```

i get the current custom user from `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

16.3.3 Defining @RequestMapping handler methods

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

`java.security.Principal` containing the currently authenticated user.

```
@Secured({"ROLE_REGULAR_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"})
@RequestMapping(value = "/context")
public ModelAndView get(Pricipal principal) {
    String username = principal.getName();
    // Continue processing...
    return null;
}
```